Phrase request for the idiom "frog in a well"?
I was arguing with my Indian friend, and he called me frog in a well in my native language (hindi)
I had not heard that phrase before, and found it very clever and on-point (not for me, but in general)
I think the aforementioned phrase describes a lot of people I know, so I was wondering there are other witty phrases meaning the same.
My research(ChatGPT) gave me 
1: Big fish in a small pond. (But the people I know are not even "big" fish)
2: Living in a bubble. (I can't think of the "bubble" they are in)
Any recommendations?
Edit:
As suggested in the comments,(In summary) I am looking for a word/phrase which conveys the same meaning as the phrase "frog in the well"/"narrow minded person".

They aren't common outside of extremely online subcultures, but I'm fond of "stuck watching shadow puppets in plato's cave", "needs to touch grass", or "guy who has only ever seen boss baby: getting a lot of boss baby vibes from this movie"

@Kaia I have seen "touch some grass" a few times. Do you know the origin/idea behind that? particularly the word "grass".

frog in a/the well is originally Japanese, not Indian. But it doesn't immediately mean much to most Anglophones, who would be more likely to associate it with Ding, Dong, Bell: Pussy's in the Well, where the point is the cat is stuck in the well (hence in danger of drowning). But frogs don't drown so easily as kittens. The Japanese proverb alludes to the frog's restricted view of the world, which is more or less the same as the Plato's Cave allegory.

big fish in a small pond and living in a bubble are both completely different from each other and different from frog in a well (which isn't exactly the same as Plato's cave). That's four metaphors for four different situations. What is the exact meaning you're trying to convey?

@FumbleFingers they(small pond/living in a bubble) were Chatgpt recommendations. I wanted similar phrase to "frog in a well".

I have voted to close this question because it seeks a phrase or expression but doesn’t specify the expression’s intended meaning intended. Pointing people to a Wikipedia article isn’t the same as formulating a complete question.

@PaulTanenbaum I requested a phrase which has the same meaning "frog in a well" has; which I think means "being narrow minded".

But look at what you just wrote: you want a phrase that means the same as another whose meaning you don’t know for sure. (!)

Is your intended meaning an attitude? Or a person? Or perhaps an action? Or a behavior? And of what kind?

@PaulTanenbaum I don't know why there is misunderstanding. Somebody I know used the phrase "frog in a well" to describe me. I am sure that means being narrow minded (I shouldn't have used "I think" there.) I wanted similar phrase to that.(describing a person). Since this is a google search/basic look-up question, I included the results I found.

That’s fine. So I would suggest you edit your question to specify that you are looking for an expression that conveys the idea of “narrow-minded person.”

"other witty phrases" leaves open the possibility of making one up.

You're like a fish born in a bowl.

And it seems other people have already found it an apt metaphor too.
